# any youtube partial data api for video stream?

Tags: youtube-api

this is my question a few days ago.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387167/can-i-sectionalize-and-concat-with-youtube-api

I searched for one week of sample iPhone application that achieved that goal. DragonTape
https://itunes.apple.com/app/dragontape/id427536318?mt=8#

DragonTape can stream some partial youtube video stream with like below URL.. 
http://r13---sn-i3b7sn7d.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?expire=1363623193&key=yt1&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&id=f0a815a965703fad&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&ip=124.66.184.4&ms=au&cp=U0hVSFZNUV9OTUNONV9OR1VCOjF6SjRwWGVhVTdQ&mv=m&source=youtube&upn=EoRgd9rUIhE&itag=18&ipbits=8&fexp=919113%2C923127%2C916626%2C902530%2C920704%2C912806%2C902000%2C919512%2C929901%2C913605%2C906938%2C931202%2C931401%2C908529%2C930803%2C920201%2C929602%2C930101%2C930603%2C926403%2C900824&mt=1363598111&newshard=yes&signature=3211547465FA17203E41F50540FF66BE0B4E33B5.3DE28CA09A9E45F1ACC242F3C91BB4259381C6FF

but i cannot find any youtube DATA API for creating above URL. that is just generated by  JavaScript/iFrame/Flash Youtube Player API. but cannot by youtube data API. 
i think that is hacked a little.

best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer on [How to do post-processing on YouTube videos for simple video effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457559/)

This kind of URL is violating [Youtube TOS](http://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) and gets blocked.

Comment: thank you for your reply.

So you mean the DragonTape is illegal servie on the basis of Youtube TOS? Perhaps they would have done some hacking, but The DragonTape is famous Youtube video editing service(in web,iPhone,iPad) I think there are some tricks for achieve feature editing. or use Youtube private API for B2B something like that.